# Aligning Select Element

Tags: css

I'm having a hard time figuring out how I can get my select element on the left side to align properly with the rest of that div so it looks more aligned. Any thoughts?

http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/cpanel

Anybody have any ideas?

**EDIT :**

I was able to correct the size and alignment of the dropdown thanks to the answer below however when you click the dropdown and it shows the empty options, which is fine for now, the size of the search and rest of the dropdown is still the original size. How can this also be corrected?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Do you want it to left-align with the block above it ('Character Profile' dropdown) or the list below ('Biography' et al).

Comment: Thanks for the replies I'd rather have it aligned with Character Profile above. I think it'd look better.

Comment: Any ideas on this issue?

Comment: have you tried any code?  it would be helpful to see what you've tried / what your using currently so we can modify or change what YOU'VE done.

Comment: I tried changing the width of it but I'm not sure I want to even do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add padding or a margin to the left of that particular element or element that contains it so it pushes it over to the left from where it sits.. you might have to play with the width setting of that particular containing element so it doesn't push everything else off to the right and leave it still looking messy. But, I'd likely pad it or give it a margin specifically on the left side so it pushes it over

Answer (score 2):

Just by adding a few properties to the ID for the select element this should flush align it on both sides.

`#usercharacter_chzn {
width:220px;
margin-left:26px;
}`

I kind of just eyeballed the alignment, it may be a pixel or two off on the width.

If you cannot find the rogue JS plugin that is creating an element.style width, you can always use the `!important` rule.

`#usercharacter_chzn {
width:220px !important;
margin-left:26px;
}`

Comment: Thanks for the response but for some reason its getting overwritten because the width is getting created with js from this template.

Comment: Updated my response, take another look.

Comment: That's awesome but what about the text box that shows up when you click the dropdown it is bigger than the select box.

Comment: you have to resize everything to your liking element by element. Its not fun I know, but thats the general set back to using pre-canned templates/code. Making it bend to your whims :-D